# Can a subprocess started by `start-process` outlive the parent emacs process?

Tags: asynchronous, emacs, elisp, multiprocessing, parent-child

I am writing some code in Emacs Lisp where I want to start a subprocess using `start-process` or a similar function. However, when the parent emacs process exits, I don't want the subprocess to exit. However, it seems that exiting the parent emacs process always kills all the subprocesses as well. The following code snippet demonstrates this:

```
(require 'async)
(async-sandbox
 (lambda () 
   (require 'package)
   (package-initialize)
   (require 'async)
   (shell-command "{ echo -n 'SPAWNING: '; date; } > ~/temp/ASYNC_LOG")
   (start-process-shell-command "subproc" nil
    "{ echo -n 'STARTED: '; date; } >> ~/temp/ASYNC_LOG;
     sleep 5;
     { echo -n 'FINISHED: '; date; } >> ~/temp/ASYNC_LOG;")
   (shell-command "{ echo -n 'SPAWNED: '; date; } >> ~/temp/ASYNC_LOG")
   (shell-command "sleep 2")
   (shell-command "{ echo -n 'FINISHED WAITING: '; date; } >> ~/temp/ASYNC_LOG")
   ))
```

This code spawns one emacs process synchronously `(async-sandbox (lambda () ...)` so that we can quit that process to trigger the problem. That process then spawns a subprocess asynchronously `(start-process-shell-command ...)`. The parent process sleeps for 2 seconds, while the subprocess sleeps for 5, so the parent process will exit first. When I run this code, I never see the "FINISHED" line in the log file, indicating that the subprocess is killed after 2 seconds. If I change the parent to wait for 7 seconds, then I see the FINISHED line in the output.

So is there any similar way to start a subprocess so that it won't be killed when its parent exits?

Comment: Which line, please, in the ASYNC_LOG indicates unexpected behavior?  `SPAWNING: Mon Nov 11 12:53:25 UTC 2013`;  `STARTED: Mon Nov 11 12:53:25 UTC 2013`;  `SPAWNED: Mon Nov 11 12:53:25 UTC 2013`;  `FINISHED WAITING: Mon Nov 11 12:53:27 UTC 2013`;  `FINISHED: Mon Nov 11 12:53:30 UTC 2013`?

Comment: The FINISHED line never appears if the subprocess is sleeping longer than the parent, indicating that the subprocess is killed when the parent exits.

Comment: I reversed it so that the parent process sleeps for 2 seconds, and the subprocess sleeps for 5 seconds, and this is what I got:  `SPAWNING: Mon Nov 11 13:28:36 UTC 2013`; `STARTED: Mon Nov 11 13:28:36 UTC 2013`; `SPAWNED: Mon Nov 11 13:28:36 UTC 2013`; `FINISHED: Mon Nov 11 13:28:38 UTC 2013`; `FINISHED WAITING: Mon Nov 11 13:28:41 UTC 2013`.  I'm not using `(require 'async)`, and I turned `async-sandbox` into an `(interactive)` function without using `lambda ()`.  I'm using OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8 with Emacs Trunk.

Comment: My example already has the parent process sleeping for 2 seconds and the subprocess sleeping for 5 seconds. From the timestamps in your comment it looks like you did the opposite. Anyway, the example doesn't work without the `async-sandbox` call, since the point is to have the parent process (which is started by `async-sandbox`) exit before the child (which is started by `start-process`). Another way to make it work is to run it in `emacs -batch` since that is what async does anyway.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to better understand the issue.  I've installed https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async and can confirm the same behavior as described in your question (using OSX 10.6.8 with a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk).  However, I do not yet have a solution -- sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I start stuff from dired:

```
(require 'dired-aux)
(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user
      '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince")
        ("\\.eps\\'" "evince")
        ("\\.jpe?g\\'" "eog")
        ("\\.png\\'" "eog")
        ("\\.gif\\'" "eog")
        ("\\.tex\\'" "pdflatex" "latex")
        ("\\.\\(?:mp4\\|mkv\\|avi\\|flv\\)\\'" "vlc")))
(defvar dired-filelist-cmd
  '(("vlc" "-L")))
(defun dired-start-process (cmd &optional file-list)
  (interactive
   (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg)))
     (list
      (dired-read-shell-command "& on %s: " current-prefix-arg files)
      files))) 
  (apply
   #'start-process
   (list cmd nil shell-file-name shell-command-switch
         (format "nohup 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null %s \"%s\""
                 (if (> (length file-list) 1)
                     (format "%s %s"
                             cmd
                             (cadr (assoc cmd dired-filelist-cmd)))
                   cmd)
                 (mapconcat #'expand-file-name file-list "\" \"")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What Emacs does upon termination is to send a signal to its spawned processes (I assume they are those present in `process-list`).  This behavior is hardcoded in Emacs C code (you could try to hack process-list removing the process you want to outlive Emacs, but I am not sure about the side effects of that; possibly they will be ugly)

You can find out what signal Emacs sends easily (just write a signal handler for one of your processes).  I would guess it is SIGHUP, so the processes know that connection to the user (Emacs) has been lost.

What you can do is to make your process to handle SIGHUP in such a way it does not die, by adding a handler for that signal for instance.  If you have zero control over that process code, you may wrap it with a "nohup" (this is what @abo-abo is basically doing; see abo-abo other answer for implementation details)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `call-process-shell-command` with the *`destination`* argument set to `0`.

From the documentation of [`call-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html):

> The argument *destination* says where to put the process output. Here are the possibilities:
>
> …
>
> 0
> Discard the output, and return `nil` immediately without waiting for the subprocess to finish.
> In this case, the process is not truly synchronous, since it can run in parallel with Emacs; but you can think of it as synchronous in that Emacs is essentially finished with the subprocess as soon as this function returns.
> MS-DOS doesn’t support asynchronous subprocesses, so this option doesn’t work there.

(From an answer by [dalanicolai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6837095/dalanicolai) on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22363/possible-to-detach-a-child-process/65040#65040)